# pointer not updating the value it is pointing to inside void function

Tags: c++, pointers

I've made a simple function that simple does the addition and absolute difference between the parameters using pointers, but when I try to update the pointer, the pointer still has the old value. why is this so, or what am I doing wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib> 

void update(int *a,int *b) {
int temp = *a;
int temp2 = *b;
int temp3 =0;
temp3 = temp + temp2;
printf("%d",temp3);
*b = abs(*a - *b);
 a = &temp3; // it is not updating
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

the pointer a is not updating and still retains its old value inside the function update

Comment: Remember that function arguments in C++ by default are passed *by value*, that is the values are *copied* into the argument variables. So when you modify `a` you modify a copy, not the original value (the value of `pa` from the `main` function).

Comment: Besides, what you're attempting to do is to make `a` point to a *local* variable inside the `update` function. The life-time of local variables ends when the function ends, and such pointers would become invalid immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is a copy of the pointer that was passed. At the end of `update`, `a` is lost. When you do this:

```
a = &temp3;
```

You change the value of `a`, but that doesn't matter, because `a` is gone after that anyway. Instead, assign the value to where it's pointing at, much like you did with `b`:

```
*a = temp3;
```

You could also use references instead of pointers:

```
void update(int &a, int &b) {
    int temp = a;
    int temp2 = b;
    int temp3 = temp + temp2;
    printf("%d ", temp3);
    b = abs(a - b);
    a = temp3;
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(a, b);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is because in `a = &temp3;` you're assigning an memory address of parameter temp3 which is probably in a function stack call, to `*a` parameter of function which also is laying on the function stack call.