# cannot access properly after getting pointer of a member of struct

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

In the following example, I basically tried to get the pointer of the element of the vector in the data. For me, those three methods seems to do the same thing, but the result is different :

```
123
9.88131e-324
5.61658e+259
```

and only via first method, the element is accessed properly. Could you point out my mistake and explain why these output's out these three method is different?

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
  vector<double> a;
  Data() : a(vector<double>(100, 123.0)) {};
  double* get_ptr(int idx){
    return &a[idx];
  }
  void get_ptr2(int idx, double* ptr){
    ptr = &a[idx];
  }
};

int main(){
  auto data = Data();
  std::cout << *(data.get_ptr(10)) << std::endl; 

  double value;
  data.get_ptr2(10, &value);
  std::cout << value << std::endl; 

  double* ptr;
  data.get_ptr2(10, ptr);
  std::cout << *ptr << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: `ptr = &a[idx];` in `get_ptr2` doesn't actually do anything. I'm not sure if you're trying to store the address of the variable in `ptr` or if you're trying to store the value it `ptr`, so can't help more.

Comment: @ChrisMM I want to store the address of variable in ptr.

Comment: Why return a pointer when you can return a reference instead?

Comment: `data.get_ptr2(10, &value);` can never work, but changing `void get_ptr2(int idx, double** ptr){`  with `*ptr = &a[idx];` and using `data.get_ptr2(10, &ptr);` will

Comment: This should be `operator[]`, not something called `get_ptr`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Could you explain why? Thinking naively, `ptr` in `get_ptr2` is of the type of `double*`. Thus, I thought naively setting the address `&a[idx]` to `ptr` worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pointer not updating the value it is pointing to inside void function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296699/pointer-not-updating-the-value-it-is-pointing-to-inside-void-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem you have in `get_ptr2`, e.g.:

```
  void get_ptr2(int idx, double* ptr){
    ptr = &a[idx];
  }
```

is that `ptr` will be a **copy** of the pointer from `main()`. When you change the value of `ptr` in your function, you are changing the value of the **local copy** of `ptr` and the results are never seen back in `main()`.

(**note** the following shows you how to accomplish what you are attempting, but doesn't recommend it as the proper way to do it. See comment by @tadman below your original question)

You can pass the *address of* a pointer from `main()` and update the pointer at that address, e.g.

```
  void get_ptr2(int idx, double** ptr){
    *ptr = &a[idx];
  }
```

and called as:

```
  double* ptr;
  data.get_ptr2(10, &ptr);
  std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
```

Pointer will hold the correct address and dereferencing the pointer will provide the wanted value.

Your option with `value` is a bit different. There, you can pass a pointer reference, overloading a second `get_ptr2()`, e.g.

```
  void get_ptr2(int idx, double*& ptr){
    ptr = &a[idx];
  }
```

But, you cannot pass the address of `value` which is an *rvalue* as the reference. You can create a second pointer holding the address and update the value held by the pointer, e.g.

```
  double value, *valptr = &value;
  data.get_ptr2(10, valptr);
  std::cout << *valptr << std::endl;
```

Which also outputs the desired value.

**Example Code**

The complete example would be:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
  vector<double> a;
  Data() : a(vector<double>(100, 123.0)) {};
  double* get_ptr(int idx){
    return &a[idx];
  }
  void get_ptr2(int idx, double*& ptr){
    ptr = &a[idx];
  }
  void get_ptr2(int idx, double** ptr){
    *ptr = &a[idx];
  }
};

int main(){
  auto data = Data();
  std::cout << *(data.get_ptr(10)) << std::endl; 

  double value, *valptr = &value;
  data.get_ptr2(10, valptr);
  std::cout << *valptr << std::endl; 

  double* ptr;
  data.get_ptr2(10, &ptr);
  std::cout << *ptr << std::endl; 
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/get_ptr
123
123
123
```